# Excel: Referencing Cell Range Dynamically Based on Row Search Value

Tags: excel, date, dynamic, range, formula

I am trying to create a automated calendar in Excel, *per my manager's preference*, which auto-calculates key dates for the department events.

To do so I am first creating a table of key dates based on certain values/preferences or exclusions (ex: Avoiding Weekends, company holidays, etc).  As we are a Finance department I am trying to create a listing of closing days for the first 5 business days of each new month.  I have the following formula which calculates the closing day accurately for testing purposes, but when i try to change it to the later dynamic range shown below I receive a formula error.

**Works:**

```
=IF(OR(AND(DAY([@Date])<8,[@[Day of Week]]<>"Sat",[@[Day of Week]]<>"Sun",[@Holiday]<>"Holiday Date"),AND(DAY([@Date])=8,COUNTIF($C$5:$C$12,"Holiday Date")>0)),"Closing Day","")
```

**Works to find the row number of first day in the new month, for searching for Company Holidays dynamically:**

```
ROW(INDEX([Holiday], MATCH(DATE(2020,MONTH([@Date]),1), [Date], 0)))
```

**Range would then be**

```
ROW(INDEX([Holiday], MATCH(DATE(2020,MONTH([@Date]),1), [Date], 0)))+7
```

**Doesn't Work:**

```
=IF(OR(AND(DAY([@Date])<8,[@[Day of Week]]<>"Sat",[@[Day of Week]]<>"Sun",[@Holiday]<>"Holiday Date"),AND(DAY([@Date])=8,COUNTIF(CONCATENATE("C",ROW(INDEX([Holiday], MATCH(DATE(2020,MONTH([@Date]),1), [Date], 0))),":C",ROW(INDEX([Holiday], MATCH(DATE(2020,MONTH([@Date]),1), [Date], 0)))+7),"Holiday Date")>0)),"Closing Day","")
```

The only Piece I am trying to add is the above italicized dynamic range reference to the cells where a holiday would appear within the first 7 days of a new month, to see if the eighth day should be considered a closing day.  I receive an error that there is a problem with the formula when I add this CONCATENATE range in though.  However, it works when I use a static range in the COUNTIF statement.

Any advice, or alternative to identifying how I can accomplish this, would be most helpful.

Change log:
** Updated table image **
** Looked to attach sample table, but unable to attach a document **

[image]

Comment: If you can, post a sample file.

Comment: @RicardoDiaz  I have made an example table, but there doesn't seem to be any way for me to attach it directly to the forum post.

Comment: You can use onedrive or google drive and post the link

Comment: @RicardoDiaz, [link](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1LdKzn7eeVHR1dLu46hNRnw6b8dx3H7RA)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't check all formulas, but as per the error using the concatenate function, you have to use `INDIRECT` when you want to convert a string to a reference (be a cell, range, sheet, workbook, formula, etc.)

In this case, try this:

```
=IF(OR(AND(DAY([@Date])<8,[@[Day of Week]]<>"Sat",[@[Day of Week]]<>"Sun",[@Holiday]<>"Holiday Date"),AND(DAY([@Date])=8,COUNTIF(INDIRECT(CONCATENATE("C",ROW(INDEX([Holiday], MATCH(DATE(2020,MONTH([@Date]),1), [Date], 0))),":C",ROW(INDEX([Holiday], MATCH(DATE(2020,MONTH([@Date]),1), [Date], 0)))+7)),"Holiday Date")>0)),"Closing Day","")
```

Let me know if it works

Comment: Thank you, that seems to work perfectly!  I believe the issue is that I was trying to use INDIRECT or CONCATENATE, but never tried to use both by nesting the functions together to do the range reference.  Thank you once again!

Comment: Excellent. Remember to mark the answer so other may find it